# Run file when .tar.gz file is opened

Tags: shell, download, executable, tar, gzip

I am trying to make an executable link in an email for mac, so I don't want it to be a `.exe` file. I tried using a `.command` file so that it will run when you click on it, but it said it's from an unidentified developer and I don't want the recipient to have to change their security settings. So I want to use a `.tar.gz` file that has a shell script in it.

The problem is that when you click the link, it downloads but doesn't automatically run the shell script. I need to know when the file is unzipped so I can run the shell script inside. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't reasonable to expect to be able to run an arbitrary script on user's machine, without him explicitly asking to run it (e.g. if all he's doing is *downloading* a file, or *opening* a non-executable file).

If the OS allowed that, it would be a serious security breach.